# How can I return value from Promise Sequelize

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I want to pull a variable that is returning the total value of the user's Cart, but says that the variable does not exist.

```js
Cart.findAll({where: {userId: 1}}).then((cart) =>{
    if (cart != undefined) {

        let price = []
        let quantity = []

        cart.forEach((item) => {
            price.push(item.price * item.quantity)
        })

        const total = Number(price.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0))
        return total
    }
})

MercadoPago.configure({
    sandbox: true,
    access_token: ''
})

router.get('/pay', islogged, async (req, res) => {

    let id = '' + Date.now()

    let data = {
        items: [
            item = {
                id: id,
                title: "",
                description: '',
                quantity: 1,
                currency_id: "BRL",
                unit_price: parseFloat(total) // here <<<<
            }
        ], 

        payer: {
            email: req.session.user['email']
        },
        auto_return : "all",
        external_reference: id,
        back_urls: {
            success: getFullUrl(req) + '/success',
            failure: getFullUrl(req) + '/failure',
            pending: getFullUrl(req) + '/pending'
        }
    }

    try {

        let payment = await MercadoPago.preferences.create(data)
        return res.redirect(payment.body.init_point)
        
    } catch(err) {
        return res.send(err.message)
    }

})
```

This `total` variable that I wanted to get. Explaining better, I need to access the total variable within the payment route, to add the total value of the product. However, as it is inside Promise, I do not have access to this variable, this is the error

Comment: Can you tell the exact error?

Comment: @HemantJain total is not defined

Comment: trying to pull the function, it returns undefined

Comment: How do you check a result of the function?

Comment: Please show the complete code. Where are you using `total`? On what line precisely do you get the error?

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: @Bergi I need to access the total variable, which is inside the promise, in the payment route, over there in the unit_price

Comment: @Snarloff Since you're already using `async`/`await`, the solution is to simply `await` it. But surely the `/pay` route won't always pay the total amount for the cart of user 1?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by doing this:

```js
async function getTotal(req) {
    const cart = await Cart.findAll({where: {userId: req.session.user['id']}})
    if (cart !== undefined) {
        let price = []
        let quantity = []

        cart.forEach((item) => {
            price.push(item.price * item.quantity)
        })

        return Number(price.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0))
    }
}
```

Thank you all!